Derivative of inverse of linear sum of matrices
I have a structural system with element stiffness matrices represented by $E_iK_i$, where $E_i$ is a scalar and $K_i$ is a $n\times n$ matrix. The global stiffness matrix is given by:
$$
K=\sum_{i=1}^{N_e}E_iK_i
$$
Where $K$ is a positive-definite and invertible $n\times n$ matrix. I'm interesting in calculating the derivative of $K^{-1}$ with respect to $E_i$. I have calculated this as:
$$
\frac{\partial K^{-1}}{\partial E_i}=-K^{-1}\frac{\partial K}{\partial E_i}K^{-1} \\
\frac{\partial K^{-1}}{\partial E_i}=-K^{-1}K_iK^{-1}
$$
This form is ok, but I was hoping to simplify the $K^{-1}$ values somehow so the formula is explicitly in terms of the $E_i$'s and $K_i$'s. Doing some small examples symbolically in Matlab, I found an interesting attribute of this system was that the derivative was always only in terms of $E_i$, and not any of the other $E$ values. So, the derivative could be expressed as:
$$
\frac{\partial K^{-1}}{\partial E_i}=f(E_i)
$$
Where $f$ is some function only in terms of $E_i$. I'm not sure how show that this is true in general, but I think it might have something to do with $K$ being positive definite. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

unless the $K_i$ are in some sense orthogonal to each other, you cannot hope to avoid the other $E_j$

Suppose that I can enforce that the $K_i$'s are orthogonal to each other (where orthogonal means $trace(AB^T)=0$), how could this simplify the inverse of the sum of these matrices?

still no (there are counterexamples in 2x2 diagonal positive definite matrices). You need way stronger conditions.

I think it may hold if $K_i$ are orthogonal and they are all positive semidefinite
